# git files not being removed from heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I've got an app I'm trying to load onto heroku, and I've removed a file called varieties.rb.

I ran `git -u` to update the directory and remove the files, and then `git add .` I then committed with `git commit -m "removed the error causing file"`.

when I run `git ls-files` it the offending file `admin/variety.rb` is not in the list. 
I then push to heroku, and get the error

```
2012-12-03T23:08:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/admin/varieties.rb:1:in
 `': uninitialized constant Variety (NameError)
```

which leads me to believe that for some reason when pushing to heroku, heroku is only updating, the files and not removing the deleted files.

Shouldn't the push command sync all the files, and not just update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently `git add -A` resolved the issue. Not sure why, as from what I understand it is the same as `git add -U` followed by `git add .`